# Max number of DocuSign Sandbox Users

Tags: docusignapi

Anyone know of a hard limit to the number of users I can have in a Sandbox environment.  We have a number of technical sales personnel that need to be able to demo our integrations to customers.  I'm wondering if i can make them all users account admins within the same sandbox or if i should just tell each of them to get their own sandbox.  The potential upside to having everyone share is we can pre-configure a few things with the sandbox integrator key, standard templates, etc etc.

thanks,

-mike

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to users in Demo on a single account.

Questions such as this should be asked over on the [DocuSign Community Forums](https://community.docusign.com/) though, it's not programming related or contact [DocuSign Customer Support](https://www.docusign.com/support).

Comment: Let me be more specific.  Is there a limit to the amount of individual API users? ... Now it's programming related.

Comment: The answer is still the same, no limit on amount of users. There is a limit on the amount of API calls you can have per hour (default 1000). But once again that's more application functionality than programming.